# SQL Server Replace Nulls in Outer Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I'm joining 2 tables with an Outer Join.

```
SELECT
    T1.DATE, 
    T2.DATE, 
    COALESCE(T2.ID, -1), 
FROM Table1 as T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 as T2 ON t1.date = t.date;
```

Sample result:

```
TABLE1.DATE =  03/15  03/16   03/17     03/18    03/19   03/30
TABLE2.DATE =  NULL   03/16   03/17     NULL     NULL    03/20
TABLE2.ID   =  -1     20      30        -1       -1      40
```

Looking for a way to replace the -1 with values from the most recent match.

I.E. on 3/15 the date will be NULL but on 03/16 I need to set the ID based upon data for 03/16 and populate the value 20 for both 03/15 and 03/16.

Then again on 03/20 I need to populate the value 40 into 03/18, 03/19, and 03/20.

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result as well. Also, row after row, with proper columns, is so much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `outer apply` instead:

```
SELECT T1.DATE, T2.DATE as effective_date,
       T2.ID
FROM Table1 T1 OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) T2.*
      FROM TABLE2 as T2
      WHERE t1.date <= t.date
      ORDER BY t2.date DESC
     ) T2;
```

Note that the second column returns the date associated with the `id` rather than the matching date from `t1`.